# Extracting multiple zip files using CMD, without 3rd party tools

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, zip

I have a cobbled together batch script that can extract a single zip file using built in VBS. I am now attempting to get it to read multiple files in the folder, and append the datetime stamp to the filename before saving.

Working for one file is this:

```
cd /d %~dp0
Call :UnZipFile "%~dp0UNZIPPED\" "%~dp0dvt_trans_C_20190517123318.dat.zip"
exit /b

:UnZipFile <ExtractTo> <newzipfile>
set vbs="%temp%\_.vbs"
if exist %vbs% del /f /q %vbs%
>%vbs%  echo Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
>>%vbs% echo If NOT fso.FolderExists(%1) Then
>>%vbs% echo fso.CreateFolder(%1)
>>%vbs% echo End If
>>%vbs% echo set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
>>%vbs% echo set FilesInZip=objShell.NameSpace(%2).items
>>%vbs% echo objShell.NameSpace(%1).CopyHere(FilesInZip)
>>%vbs% echo Set fso = Nothing
>>%vbs% echo Set objShell = Nothing
cscript //nologo %vbs%
if exist %vbs% del /f /q %vbs%
```

Trying to loop with /r :

```
setlocal
cd /d %~dp0
for /r %%v in (*.zip) do
Call :UnZipFile "%~dp0UNZIPPED\" "%%v"
exit /b
```

Doesn't seem to be passing filename(s) to vbs

Then I am trying to append datetime to the end of the file name, here:

`>>%vbs% echo objShell.NameSpace(%1).CopyHere(FilesInZip)`

But I'm not even sure where to start.

Ideas?

Comment: `"%%v"` -> `"%%~fv"`, but frankly, I'd simply drop batch and use VBScript directly.

Comment: I'd love to, but the I'm limited to what I can call from our vendors interface software. .bat files are allowed, so that's what I'm working with :p
Can you explain why ~fv would resolve?

Comment: Resolved recursion:
for /r %%G in (*.zip) do Call :UnZipFile "%~dp0UNZIPPED\" "%%G" - this was on two lines, not one. works fine now. Still trying to amend file names

Comment: Are you trying to append current date time to the zipfile name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All working with:

```
setlocal
cd /d %~dp0
for /r %%G in (*.zip) do Call :UnZipFile "%~dp0UNZIPPED\" "%%G"
exit /b

:UnZipFile <ExtractTo> <newzipfile>
set vbs="%temp%\_.vbs"
if exist %vbs% del /f /q %vbs%
>%vbs%  echo Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
>>%vbs% echo If NOT fso.FolderExists(%1) Then
>>%vbs% echo fso.CreateFolder(%1)
>>%vbs% echo End If
>>%vbs% echo set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
>>%vbs% echo set FilesInZip=objShell.NameSpace(%2).items
>>%vbs% echo objShell.NameSpace(%1).CopyHere(FilesInZip)
>>%vbs% echo Set fso = Nothing
>>%vbs% echo Set objShell = Nothing
cscript //nologo %vbs%
if exist %vbs% del /f /q %vbs%
cd /d %~dp0UNZIPPED
ren *.dat "* %Date:/= % %Time::=.%.*"
```

Comment: So you are good then? I have code for this but wont post unless it's still needed.

Comment: I would rather use non locale specific date as this might not work on all systems.